# Analyse time difference between events in repeating sequence in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` ordered by DateTime like below and want to analyse the time difference between ID = 1 and the ID's 2 to 5, separated by state and the repeating sequences of the state.

```
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1533081601.42, 1533081601.98, 
                                      1533081601.98, 1533081601.98, 1533081602.02, 1533081928.06, 1533081928.22, 
                                      1533081928.22, 1533081928.22, 1533081928.22, 1533081952.34, 1533081952.94, 
                                      1533081952.94, 1533081952.94, 1533081952.98, 1533081953.98, 1533081954.14, 
                                      1533081954.14, 1533081954.14, 1533081954.14), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                              "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ID = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                                                                                                                5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), state = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "data.frame"))
```

ID 1 is always first in a sequence but the order of ID's 2 -5 after ID 1 is changing. The sequence of state(s) is just a repeating of 0 and 1.

For each run of the IDs 1 to 5 having the same state (1 or 0) I want to get the time difference between ID 1 and the other IDs.

A `data.table()` approach is preferred but any advice is welcome!!!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each run of ID1 to the next ID1 has the same state, or is it an additional requirement that they need to have the same stat?

Comment: Exactly, each run of ID 1 to the next ID 1 has the same state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposed that the data is given in the correct order,

```
library(data.table)
df[, time_diff := round(DateTime - first(DateTime), 3L), by = cumsum(ID == 1)][]
```

will return

> ```
>                DateTime ID state time_diff
>  1: 2018-08-01 00:00:01  1     0 0.00 secs
>  2: 2018-08-01 00:00:01  3     0 0.56 secs
>  3: 2018-08-01 00:00:01  4     0 0.56 secs
>  4: 2018-08-01 00:00:01  5     0 0.56 secs
>  5: 2018-08-01 00:00:02  2     0 0.60 secs
>  6: 2018-08-01 00:05:28  1     1 0.00 secs
>  7: 2018-08-01 00:05:28  2     1 0.16 secs
>  8: 2018-08-01 00:05:28  3     1 0.16 secs
>  9: 2018-08-01 00:05:28  4     1 0.16 secs
> 10: 2018-08-01 00:05:28  5     1 0.16 secs
> 11: 2018-08-01 00:05:52  1     0 0.00 secs
> 12: 2018-08-01 00:05:52  3     0 0.60 secs
> 13: 2018-08-01 00:05:52  4     0 0.60 secs
> 14: 2018-08-01 00:05:52  5     0 0.60 secs
> 15: 2018-08-01 00:05:52  2     0 0.64 secs
> 16: 2018-08-01 00:05:53  1     1 0.00 secs
> 17: 2018-08-01 00:05:54  2     1 0.16 secs
> 18: 2018-08-01 00:05:54  3     1 0.16 secs
> 19: 2018-08-01 00:05:54  4     1 0.16 secs
> 20: 2018-08-01 00:05:54  5     1 0.16 secs
> ```

The grouping variable is created on the fly with `by = cumsum(ID == 1)`, so it is advanced every time an ID1 is encountered. Then, a new column is created by reference, i.e., without copying the whole data object.

As each group starts with ID1 we can safely use `first(DateTime)` instead of 
 `DateTime[ID == 1]` thereby avoiding another lookup operation.

Comment: Works perfect and fast! My first approach was using rle() to get the grouping but this is way more advanced. Thank you!

Comment: As a matter of fact I was going to propose an alternative approach which would use    `rleid(state)` for grouping. But this potentially would fail if there are two subsequent groups with the same state. Following your problem description, looking for occurrences of ID1 appears to be safer.

Comment: Yes, the state is an extra information. Still i need to consider the problems there as well but this is done in the data cleaning process happening before coming to this problem! Thanks again Uwe!

Comment: +1 for the answer (had a highly similar one so deleted it); I'm writing since I think not only `rleid` would lead to problems but is likely also slower, so unless really needed `cumsum` shouldn't be avoided in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a duplicate of the original table:

```
dt<-
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1533081601.42, 1533081601.98, 
                                      1533081601.98, 1533081601.98, 1533081602.02, 1533081928.06, 1533081928.22, 
                                      1533081928.22, 1533081928.22, 1533081928.22, 1533081952.34, 1533081952.94, 
                                      1533081952.94, 1533081952.94, 1533081952.98, 1533081953.98, 1533081954.14, 
                                      1533081954.14, 1533081954.14, 1533081954.14), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                              "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ID = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                                                                                                                5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), state = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "data.frame"))

setorder(dt,ID,DateTime)
dt[,run:=1:.N,by=ID]
dt2 = copy(dt)
dt3 = merge(dt[ID==1],dt2,by=c("state","run"),allow.cartesian=T)
dt3[,timediff:=DateTime.y -DateTime.x]
dt4 = dt3[ID.x==1 & ID.y %in% c(2:5)]
setnames(dt4,c("DateTime.y","ID.y"),c("DateTime","ID"))
result = merge(dt,dt4[,list(DateTime,ID,state,run,timediff)],by=c("DateTime","ID","state","run"),all.x=T)
```

Using cartesian while merging can be problematic if your data is huge though

Comment: This works as well but as you mentioned my data sets are really huge (machine log data). But thanks for posting the solution!